# From which dark matter made of?

Tags: cosmology, universe, dark-matter

Observations indicate that about 90 percent of the matter itself in the
universe is made up of [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter). Exactly what kind of things dark matter made of?

Comment: In your very own reference there is a section summing up all present hypotheses. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Composition

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @my2cts *your very own reference* That reference was added by a moderator.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

We are still not fully sure about exactly what dark matter consists of or what it's structure. They are however classified as $WIMPS$ or Weakly Interacting Massive Particles. These are hypothetical particles in which main component (or maybe only component) is dark matter.

- So far only concrete knowledge that we have for dark matter is their interaction via gravitational force *

Comment: Dark matter is not "classified as WIMPs" (in fact the usage in the answer is circular). WIMPs are, however, a potential candidate for dark matter.

Comment: Perhaps you should have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Composition before answering.

Comment: @Nihar Karve, oh my bad I did messed up this. I will take care of it in future.